# How to insert text with single quotation sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, quotes, quotations

I want to insert text with single quote 
Eg john's to table  in sql server 2005 database

Comment: but adding another single quote with existing one will create problem while saving the data into another table
eg.: insert into table1(select * from table2)

Answer (score 23):

Escape single quote with an additional single as Kirtan pointed out 
And if you are trying to execute a dynamic sql (which is not a good idea in the first place) via sp_executesql then the below code would work for you

```
sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO SomeTable (SomeColumn) VALUES (''John''''s'')'
```

Answer (score 19):

The answer really depends on how you are doing the `INSERT`.

If you are specifying a SQL literal then you need to use the double-tick approach:

```
-- Direct insert
INSERT INTO Table1 (Column1) VALUES ('John''s')

-- Using a parameter, with a direct insert
DECLARE @Value varchar(50)
SET @Value = 'John''s'
INSERT INTO Table1 (Column1) VALUES (@Value)

-- Using a parameter, with dynamic SQL
DECLARE @Value varchar(50)
SET @Value = 'John''s'
EXEC sp_executesql 'INSERT INTO Table1 (Column1) VALUES (@p1)', '@p1 varchar(50)', @Value
```

If you are doing the INSERT from code, use parameters:

```
// Sample ADO.NET
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand()) {
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (Column1) VALUES (@Value)";

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", "John's");

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

If your data contains user-input, direct or indirect, **USE PARAMETERS**.  Parameters protect against SQL Injection attacks.  Never ever build up dynamic SQL with user-input.

Comment: thank you ...
but this code will not work for dynamic update querry

Comment: Can you give more detail on your query?  Parameters will work in nearly all queries.  I'm curious why they won't work in your case.

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me:

```
  INSERT INTO [TABLE]
  VALUES ('text','''test.com''', 1)
```

Basically, you take the single quote you want to insert and replace it with two. So if you want to insert a string of text ('text') and add single quotes around it, it would be ('''text'''). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Column1) VALUES ('John''s')
```

Or you can use a stored procedure and pass the parameter as -

```
usp_Proc1 @Column1 = 'John''s'
```

If you are using an INSERT query and not a stored procedure, you'll have to escape the quote with two quotes, else its OK if you don't do it.

Comment: how it can be possible when the value comes from a variable

Comment: @solairaja - @somevar = 'Test''s'

Answer (score 1):

This answer works in SQL Server 2005, 2008, 2012.

At times the value has MANY single quotes. Rather than add a single quote next to each single quote as described above with `'John''s'`. And there are examples using the `REPLACE` function to handle many single quotes in a value.

Try the following. This is an update statement but you can use it in an `INSERT` statement as well.

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF

DECLARE @s VARCHAR(1000)

SET @s = "SiteId:'1'; Rvc:'6'; Chk:'1832'; TrEmp:'150'; WsId:'81'; TtlDue:'-9.40'; TtlDsc:'0'; TtlSvc:'0'; TtlTax:'-0.88'; TtlPay:'0'; TipAmt:'0.00'; SvcSeq:'09'; ReTx:'N'; TraceId:'160110124347N091832';"


UPDATE TransactionPaymentPrompt
set PromptData = @s

from TransactionPaymentPrompt tpp with (nolock)
where tpp.TransactionID = '106627343'
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked how to escape an `Apostrophe character (')` in SQL Server.  All the answers above do an excellent job of explaining that.

**However, depending on the situation, the `Right single quotation mark character (’)` might be appropriate.**

*(No escape characters needed)*

```
-- Direct insert
INSERT INTO Table1 (Column1) VALUES ('John’s')
```

• Apostrophe (U+0027)

[Ascii Apostrophe on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Basic_Latin)

• Right single quotation mark (U+2019)

[Unicode Right single quotation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Unicode_symbols)