# Wrong SQL syntax SQL lServer C# winforms

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

hey I'm trying to run this query:

```
command.UseSqlCommand("INSERT INTO DisplayOrders Values ('" + OrderId.Text + "','" + "(SELECT ProductId FROM Products WHERE ProductName =N'" + listBox1.Text + "')','" + listBox1.Text + "','" + OrderQuantity.Text + "','" + TotalCost.Text + "')");
```

now the `command.UseSqlCommand` is just running the query, but I keep getting this error:
**incorrect syntax near 'intel'**

(intel is the 'ProductName' (that I'm getting from here:

```
SELECT ProductId FROM Products WHERE ProductName =N'" + listBox1.Text + "'
```

Edit : this is the value of the command , (getting the 'incorrect syntax near 'intel')

```
INSERT INTO DisplayOrders 
Values ('2', '(SELECT ProductId FROM Products WHERE ProductName =N'Intel Quad Core i5 3470 3.2Ghz 6MB Tray')','Intel Quad Core i5 3470 3.2Ghz 6MB Tray','1','900')"
```

Comment: 1) This is open to SQL injection and 2) split it into a `string`, take it's value, run that on the database yourself, see the result.

Comment: Don't do this. Please. Use parameterized SQL to avoid [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). That may well fix your immediate problem too, but it will *definitely* improve the security of your app.

Comment: What's that N  in WHERE ProductName =N'" + listBox1.Text + "')` all about? Possibly move the single quote one space left so it encompasses the N as well.

Comment: N is for Unicode on SQL Server Mr @Ash :)

Comment: Hey thanks for concern , but this is a school project and no one test me for SQLI .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the single quotes around the SELECT statement

```
command.UseSqlCommand("INSERT INTO DisplayOrders Values ('" + OrderId.Text + "'," + 
         "(SELECT ProductId FROM Products WHERE ProductName =N'" + listbox.Text +"'), " +
         "'" + listBox1.Text + "','" + OrderQuantity.Text + "','" + TotalCost.Text + "')");
```

But this code will fail if any of your listbox items contains a single quote.
I have read your comment about SQL Injection not been an issue here, but it is a good habit to use even for schoolworks. At least change to

```
string itemName = listBox1.Text.Replace("'", "''");
command.UseSqlCommand("INSERT INTO DisplayOrders Values ('" + OrderId.Text + "'," + 
         "(SELECT ProductId FROM Products WHERE ProductName =N'" + itemName +"'), " +
         "'" + itemName + "','" + OrderQuantity.Text + "','" + TotalCost.Text + "')");
```

Answer (score 3):

As others have stated you should use Parameterised queries which will overcome this issue. But to answer your question "as-is"...

You need to double-close your single quote. Best way to see this is store into a string and debug / write to trace. Example of how to double-close query here: [How to insert text with single quotation sql server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775687/how-to-insert-text-with-single-quotation-sql-server-2005)

As-is your query string will contain something like this:

```
INSERT INTO DisplayOrders Values ('1234','(SELECT ProductId FROM Products WHERE ProductName =N'Fred')'...
```

But it should really contain something like this (notice the `'''`):

```
INSERT INTO DisplayOrders Values ('1234','(SELECT ProductId FROM Products WHERE ProductName =N'''Fred''')'...
```

Otherwise you are closing the `INSERT Values` not the `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Need replace to this

```
  command.UseSqlCommand("INSERT INTO DisplayOrders Values ('" + OrderId.Text + "'," + "(SELECT IdProduct FROM Products WHERE ProductName =N'" + listBox1.Text + "'),'" + listBox1.Text + "','" + OrderQuantity.Text + "','" + TotalCost.Text + "')");
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT ProductId FROM Products WHERE ProductName =N'" + listBox1.Text + "'
```

will return a table so it is wrong to use it inside insert statement.

instead of using this , execute this command alone then get the returned value and then execute the insert statement alone

Comment: ...I don't even know where to begin with any of your answers. I suggest you learn about the topics you're replying to.