# php special characters inserting into SQL Server 2005

Tags: php, database, sql-server-2005

I currently have this query that insert data into SQL server. But as the question can contain special characters that include ' which is single quote, it skips my query and did not insert into database. 
Any idea what would work for me to be able to insert single quote data into SQL server database? 
Example: Trainer's Performance.

Here's my code for inserting data into database:

```
$sql_array = array();
    foreach ($_POST['question'] as $row => $name) {

        $question = $name;
        $qnsNo = $_POST['qnsNo'][$row];
        $input = $_POST['input'][$row];
        $options = $_POST['options'][$row];
        $others = $_POST['others'][$row];
        $compulsory = isset($_POST['compulsory'][$row]) ? $_POST['compulsory'][$row] : "";

        $idQuery = "SELECT max(surveyID) FROM scSurveyForm WHERE createBy = '$createBy' AND writeUp = '$writeUp'";
        $idResult = sqlsrv_query($conn, $idQuery);
        $rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($idResult);
        $lastID = $rows[0];

        $sql_array[] = "('" . $question . "'," . $lastID . ",'" . $qnsNo . "','" . $input . "','" . $options . "','" . $others . "','" . $compulsory . "')";

        if (!empty($question)) {

            $query_single = "INSERT INTO scFormLayout(question, surveyID, qnsNo, input, options, others, compulsory)
  VALUES" . implode(', ', $sql_array);
            //echo $query_single.'<br/>';
            $status = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query_single);
            $sql_array = array();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775687/how-to-insert-text-with-single-quotation-sql-server-2005

Comment: I tried using addslashes but the error still occurs, any idea why? ): here's a sample of it.. $sql_array[] = "('" . addslashes($question) . "'," . $id . ",'" . $qnsNo . "','" . $input . "','" . $options . "','" . $others . "','" . $compulsory . "')";  

and the error code: Incorrect syntax near 's'. Unclosed quotation mark before the character string ',',',')'.