# How to Post a SQL String With Quotes?

Tags: sql, t-sql

This seems like it would be a question that has been answered a million times before, but searching for a bit only brought up replacing single quotes with double quotes.

The problem is that I have a file with a huge number of single quotes. Is there any way to insert a string as is, without the single quotes throwing an error. Any wrapper?

This is for pure SQL, I don't need to save this string from the backend or anything. I need a SQL command.

Edit: Just to clarify - the string I am trying to post is a document, in html format, with a large number of both double and single quotes, escaping each one individually would take enough time to warrant saving data in another format, which I would rather not do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert text with single quotation sql server 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775687/how-to-insert-text-with-single-quotation-sql-server-2005)

Comment: What do you mean, you have a file?   Is it a flat file that you are trying to import?

Comment: That's a per-occurrence solution, asking if there is anything global.

Comment: Escape individually?   Really you don't have access to an editor that will do a bulk replace?

Comment: @Blam, do you know far the "f' key is from "ctrl"? I am not a gymnast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a file accessible to the SQL Server, you can read the contents in to a variable with `OPENROWSET`.  For example, to read a Unicode text file at `C:\drop\demo.html`:

```
DECLARE @DocumentText nvarchar(MAX);

SELECT @DocumentText = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\drop\demo.html', SINGLE_NCLOB) file;

INSERT INTO Files (Column) VALUES (@DocumentText);
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you replace the single quotes with two single quotes?  That is how SQL Server escapes the single quote in a string.

```
declare @test_string nvarchar(max) = 'string with a single '' quote in it';
print @test_string

string with a single ' quote in it
```

Comment: Familiar with that solution. Want to see if there is something else without touching every single quote.

Comment: @Mitch: Yea, seems like what it will be in the end. It just seemed to make sense that there would be an "ignore all single quotes" command, somehow.

Comment: Nope.  The string you are sending is either valid SQL (no embedded quotes), you are supposed to parameterize it.  (Excepting for use of things like `OPENROWSET(BULK'filename', SINGLE_BLOB)`)

Comment: How are you getting this string from the file into SQL?  You can probably add a replace command on the reading of the file.

Comment: Read-only user agreement, so I just save it by hand on the rare occasions when it's updated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double quotes:

```
select 'it''s a double quote'
```

Will return:

```
it's a double quote
```

Comment: Familiar with that solution. Want to see if there is something else without touching every single quote.

Answer (score -1):

Read the file, parse it, and do

```
    if(string.charAt(I))=="'"... charAt(I)="";
```